# Добавление и удаление класса при клике React

Tags: reactjs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нужно чтобы при клике на '+ струны' или '+ кейс' добавлялся active, при повторном клике - убирался
Мой код :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

    function GuitarBlock({ name, imageUrl, price, options, types }) {
        const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(null);
        const onSelectItem = addOption => {
            setActiveItem(addOption);[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
        };
    
        const [delivery, setDelivery] = useState(0);
        const deliveryOption = addDeliveryOption => {
            setDelivery(addDeliveryOption);
        };
    
        return (
            <div className='guitar-block'>
                <img className='guitar-block__image' src={imageUrl} alt='Guitar' />
                <h4 className='guitar-block__title'>{name}</h4>
                <div className='guitar-block__selector'>
                    <ul>
                        {types &&
                            types.map((name, addDeliveryOption) => (
                                <li
                                    className={
                                        delivery === addDeliveryOption
                                            ? 'active'
                                            : ''
                                    }
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        deliveryOption(addDeliveryOption);
                                    }}
                                    key={addDeliveryOption}
                                >
                                    {name}
                                </li>
                            ))}
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        {options &&
                            options.map((name, addOption) => (
                                <li
                                    className={
                                         activeItem ? 'active' : ''
                                    }
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        onSelectItem(addOption);
                                    }}
                                    key={addOption}
                                >
                                    {name}
                                </li>
                            ))}
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className='guitar-block__bottom'>
                    <div className='guitar-block__price'>от {price} $</div>
                    <div className='button button--outline button--add'>
                        <svg
                            width='12'
                            height='12'
                            viewBox='0 0 12 12'
                            fill='none'
                            xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                        >
                            <path
                                d='M10.8 4.8H7.2V1.2C7.2 0.5373 6.6627 0 6 0C5.3373 0 4.8 0.5373 4.8 1.2V4.8H1.2C0.5373 4.8 0 5.3373 0 6C0 6.6627 0.5373 7.2 1.2 7.2H4.8V10.8C4.8 11.4627 5.3373 12 6 12C6.6627 12 7.2 11.4627 7.2 10.8V7.2H10.8C11.4627 7.2 12 6.6627 12 6C12 5.3373 11.4627 4.8 10.8 4.8Z'
                                fill='white'
                            />
                        </svg>
                        <span>Добавить</span>
                        <i>2</i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    
    export default GuitarBlock;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

до return() нужно прописать функцию, добавляющую/убирающую класс active:

```
function toggleHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    (e.target.classList.contains("active") === true) ? e.target.classList.remove("active") : e.target.classList.add("active");
}
```

А после, задать слушатель события и повесить на него эту функцию:

```
<button onClick={toggleHandler}></button>
```

Не используйте div там, где должен быть button!

Answer (score 0):

Возможно чуть изменить стейт

```
const onSelectItem = addOption => {
    setActiveItem((prev) => {...prev, [addOption]: addOption})
};
```

И на кнопке изменить проверку

```
<ul>
    {options &&
        options.map((name, addOption) => (
            <li
                className={
                     activeItem[addOption] ? 'active' : ''
                }
                onClick={() => {
                    onSelectItem(addOption);
                }}
                key={addOption}
            >
                {name}
            </li>
        ))}
</ul>
```